# How do I give the inverse of a bijective function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I have proved the function being bijective, but I don't know how to inverse it. So if someone could please show the steps how to do it I would be very grateful. Below is the provided proofs for injective and surjective.

Given:
 *f*: $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, *f(x) = 2x+1*
Let *a,b* $ \in \mathbb{Q}$, now assume *f(a) = f(b)* 
Show that *a=b*:
*2a+1=2b+1*
*2a=2b*
Thus *a=b* function is injective.
Let *a* $\in \mathbb{Q}$, claim that $\frac{a-1}{2}$ maps to *a*. $\frac{a-1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$ since *a* $ \in \mathbb{Q}$
*f($\frac{a-1}{2}$)* = 2($\frac{a-1}{2}$)+1 
=*a-1+1*
=*a*
Thus function is surjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to find the inverse to the function $f$, we denote this inverse as $f^{-1}=g$. Now by definition of the inverse we have $f(g(x))=x$. This just means that $g$ 'undoes' what $f$ did with $x$. So if you apply $g$ to $x$ and then $f$ we get out original $x$ back. So the composition of a function with its inverse is by definition the identity map.

Mathematically this translates into
$$f(g(x)) = x.$$
We now just use the fact that we know what the function $f$ is to obtain the following expression
$$2g(x)+1=x.$$
Here we just treated $g(x)$ as a variable and filled it into the expression for $f$. We can solve this now for $g$ to get
$$g(x) = \frac{x-1}{2}.$$
We can now check to see that indeed $f(g(x)) = x$ and $g(f(x))=x$. Thus the $g$ that we found is indeed the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Is it possible if you could show it more thoroughly? I am having a hard time understanding how to go through the steps of it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I will update my answer.

Comment: I get it now! Thank you so much :)

Comment: no worries, glad to help

Comment: Nice. A more intuitive alternative to the usual practice.